# Can I get a complete simple DialogFlow example (of the current version v2) for python?

Tags: python, api, dialogflow-es

I have tried using some old tutorials but really all I need is a complete example that I can modify to fit my needs.

Just an example for python (or c++ although that would require redoing what I have so far) of DialogFlow being used in python? Just a simple interface where DialogFlow takes a string and sends back a string?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api

Comment: yes I saw that but I was unable to get it to work. That example is not complete. Could you by any chance throw together a sample main function to call it and take user input?

Comment: What problem did you have with it? I'll take a look at it now.

Comment: well I installed all the dependencies and created a main function to call that function with all of the things you listed at the bottom of your answer. It just did not work.  For some reason what you posted does work... Could you edit that with the function call inside of a function?  I now get an authorization credential error but I believe I can fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/quick/api):

```py
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs.

    Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversation."""
    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
            text=text, language_code=language_code)

        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

        response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        print('=' * 20)
        print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
        print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
            response.query_result.intent.display_name,
            response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
        print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
            response.query_result.fulfillment_text))

def main():
    project_id = 'PROJECT-ID-HERE'
    session_id = 'SESSION-ID-HERE'
    texts = ['reserve a meeting room for six people']
    language_code = 'en-US'

    detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code)

main()
```

Texts should be an iterable (list, tuple, etc) of strings.

You should also be authenticated already -- I recommend using a service account with json key as it is pretty simple to get going. There is a good example [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python).

Comment: How will I load the json key? From the file with a file read into variable or just copy and paste the json?

Comment: Use an environment variable. In the console following instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually) so before opening python in the console type `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/home/user/Downloads/[FILE_NAME].json"`

Comment: yep I actually just fixed it and was going to comment:
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = 'private_key.json'
was the line I needed

Comment: Ah yes you have to add that part in to the python as well.